# Edit/Levenstein distance with time stamp - different paths with similar (minimal) cost

Tags: algorithm, levenshtein-distance

I am using the [Edit/Levenstein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to measure similarity between words. Unlike the simplest implementation, my letters have time stamps, let's say in sample numbers N=0,1,2,...

The problem I am facing is that I can get different paths along the cost matrix which end in the same (minimal) cost, and these different paths are associated with different target string. For example, if I measure the distance between the source string `aa` and target string `bab`, and I assume the source string starts on time stamp N=0, then I have 2 paths with the same cost of 2 (one addition and one substitution):

1. Add `b` at N=-1, leave the 1st `a` as it is, and substitute the 2nd `a` with a `b`.
2. Substitute the 1st `a` with a `b`, leave the 2nd `a` as it is, and add `b` at N=2.

Aligned on the time line, these 2 results are different:

```
Time:    ... -1 0 1 2 3 ...
Source:         a a
Target1:      b a b
Target2:        b a b
```

I need to know when that happens, so I can choose between the two possible targets based on some criteria. Is there any other way other then tracing the path along the way and keeping track of all possible paths which lead to the minimal cost?

I've considered using [Dynamic Time Warp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) instead, since the time-line is part of the model in the first place, but it seems that since the cost matrix is initialized to infinity (except for the [0,0] entry), the first step will always be matching the 1st frame of the target to the 1st frame of the source, resulting in the target starting at the same time stamp as the source. Anyway, using DTW I still have to trace all paths leading to the same minimal cost.

Any help or insights are welcomed.

Comment: I am not sure about the meaning of these time stamps. One part of your question seems to indicate that you want all possible paths with minimal cost. Another part seems to indicate that you need to handle insertions at the beginning specially. In the second case I would recommend you look at subsequence DTW that can easily be adapted to subsequence Levensthein, since both are essentially the same algorithm. If I misunderstood these please be more specific about your problem.

Comment: You understand correctly - the two parts you mention are entangled - I want to be able to trace-back 2 different paths (or more). I just mentioned a problem in DTW if one of these paths contains insertion at the beginning. I will have a look at your suggestion.

Comment: I just checked your example and retracing the cost matrix I get three possible solutions that all have a cost of two (considering no special parameters to the Algorithm). If you need more sophisticated solutions you might also try changing the step conditions or the costs for each step. But I think I am still not understanding the problem correctely.

Comment: I mentioned 2 paths only as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thinking some more about your problem, it  seems a bit that there is a misunderstanding of DTW or Levensthein. Both algorithms try to squish and expand the sequences to match them with each other. So in the DTW case your example would have the following solutions:

```
Solution1:
  a a
 /| |
b a b

Solution2:
a a
| |\
b a b

Solution3:
a a
|\|\
b a b
```

If you have a look at these solutions, you will notice that all of these have a cost of 2, i.e. in all cases 2 `b`s get assigned to as. What these examples mean is, that in the first sequence one timestamp gets squished together compared to the second sequence. For example in the first solution the first two timestamps of `b a` get squished to form a single timestep corresponding to the first `a`of the second sequence (the second sequence is just reversed, the third solution is more complex). DTW is meant to deal with sequences that are played at different speed at certain parts, hence the "time-warping" analogy.

If your timesteps are really fixed and you only need to align them, without any actual warping considered, you might just try all alignments and calculate the costs.

Something like this (assuming str2 to be the shorter one):

```
for i = 0 to length( str1 ) - length( str2 ) do
  shift str2 by i to the left
  calculate number of different position between shifted str2 and str1
done
return i with lowest difference
```

Assuming you need both shifting as well as warping (something might have been added to the beginning and the timesteps might not match), then considere subsequence DTW. For this you just need to relax the boundary conditions.

Assuming you index your string at one instead of zero you can write DTW like this:

```
diff( x, y ) = 1 if str1 at x != str2 at x 
               0 otherwise

cost( 0, 0 ) = 0;
cost( 0, * ) = infinity;
cost( *, 0 ) = infinity;
cost( x, y ) = min( cost( x-1, y-1 ), cost( x-1, y ), cost( y, y-1) ) + diff( x, y )
```

DTW-Cost then is `cost( length( str1 ), length( str2 ) )` and your path can be traced back from there. For subsequence DTW you simply change this:

```
diff( x, y ) = 1 if str1 at x != str2 at x 
               0 otherwise

cost( 0, 0 ) = 0;
cost( 0, * ) = 0;
cost( *, 0 ) = infinity; // yes this is correct and needed
cost( x, y ) = min( cost( x-1, y-1 ), cost( x-1, y ), cost( y, y-1) ) + diff( x, y )
```

Then you pick your DTW-cost as `min( cost( x, length( str2 ) )` and trace back from `argmin( cost( x, length( str2 ) )`. This assumes you know one string to be the substring of the other. If you do not know this and both might only have a common warped middle you will have to do partial matching, which as far as I know is still a open research topic, since one needs to pick a notion of "optimality" which cannot clearly be defined.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I will consider the sub-sequence DTW, it seems relaxing the boundary conditions might work for me. One difference I see between Levenstein and DTW is that in DTW the cost at a given step depends on a distance measure d(i,j), and (depending on its definition), this measure can be close to zero for a substitution step, where in Levenstein you always get non-zero cost for substitution.

Comment: Yes, this is basically the main difference between DTW and Levensthein. Also if you have a look at more detailed papers on DTW there are a lot of parameters you can switch in DTW to make it compute exactely what you need. E.g. you can change the shape of the steps or add extra cost for different steps.